# Разделить строку на 5 чисел

Tags: python, split

Есть входной файл со строками типа

`"177-5.877852519E-02-8.090169947E-02 0.000000000E+00       0       0"`

Где **177** id элемента, `-5.877852519E-02` - первое число, `-8.090169947E-02` , как разбить на разные элементы, учитывая что перезаписать файл данных не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно регулярными выражениями воспользоваться, [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/385597/4279):

```
import re

print(re.findall(r"[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?", s))
```

И даже в вашем случае [работает](https://ideone.com/yukDSk):

```
['177', '-5.877852519E-02', '-8.090169947E-02', ' 0.000000000E+00', 
 '       0', '       0']
```

В строке 6 чисел , а не 5.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython_stdlib.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
import re

def split(s):
    return re.findall(r"[+-]? *(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?", s)
    
print(*map(str.strip, split("177-5.877852519E-02-8.090169947E-02 0.000000000E+00       0       0")))

# try your own input    
from browser import document, alert 
@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    print(*split(document["zone"].value))
</script>
<input id="zone" value="1.2-3.4"><button id="mybutton">Разделить !</button></body>
```